# Swift - Dependency injection in unit test

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, unit-testing

This the first time am working with dependency injection in swift an this is how I do it , I have a dataManager that is initialized in appDelegate then passed to my first view controller witch will then be passed to other view controllers every time they get pushed to screen :

```
  if let navigationCtrl = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

        if let firstViewController = navigationCtrl.topViewController as? FirstViewController {
            firstViewController.dataManager = dataManager
        }
    }
```

Now doing this, everything works great, but when I go to test each view controller, I always get dataManger to be nil, and I know it's because of the condition I gave in the first place. So is there way to make sure the topViewController always has dataManager variable without inheriting from another ViewController.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One of these is happening:

- `window` is `nil`
- `window?.rootViewController` is not a `UINavigationController`
- `navigationCtrl.topViewController` is not a `FirstViewController`
- `firstViewController.dataManager` is `nil`

It should be a simple debug. Either put some breakpoints and/or `print` statements to know where the problem is.

**Tip(s):**

- Make sure to set the view controller's class correctly in XCode/Interface-Builder.

Comment: Nice, I added a tip for that: Make sure to set the view controller's class correctly in XCode/Interface-Builder. Is it set to `FirstViewController`?

Comment: yes it is. Maybe I didn't clarify more in my question. But the problem is when testing for example thirdView controller , I don't do through the firstViewcontroller I present the third controller directly and thats why navigationCtrl.topViewController is not FirstViewController, it's third view controller in this case thus it doesn't go through the condition

Comment: I'm not sure you provided enough details for us to provide a good answer. Sounds like you have trouble preparing the view controller when doing certain segues? Could you add more details/context to your question?